# How to set default BCD store location on UEFI system

Tags: windows-10, bcd, bcdedit

I moved a Windows installation from one disk to another, using gparted. I manually created a new EFI partition using the `bcdboot` command.

The system boots fine, however, advanced startup options are not available. I suspect this is because it does know the new BCD location.

Running `bcdedit /enum` results in the following mesage:

```
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The requested system device could not be found.
```

When manually specifying a store path it does work as expected: `bcdedit /store M:/boot/bcd /enum`. (M: is the FAT32 EFI partition).

How do I configure the default BCD store?

[On legacy systems, apparently this is done by marking the partition as "active".](https://superuser.com/questions/752953/how-can-i-set-the-location-of-the-bcd-system-store-for-bcdedit) That's not possible with a GPT partition table.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by booting into Linux, and using `fdisk` to change the type of the EFI system partition. After changing it to `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B` (the GUID for the EFI system partition type), Windows now recognizes it as an EFI system partition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).